# How to follow make a dot and text follow a mouse?

Tags: vega

To get to know how events work in VEGA, I gave myself the simple exercice to render a dot and a text positioned on the cursors coordinates in a given view.

I managed to make a symbol follow the mouse coordinates, yet when I try to make two types of marks ( text and symbol) follow the mouse , it doesn't render them both but the first one appearing in the marks [ ] array.

Any ideas ?

Following specification is used in the exercice :

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 600,
  "height": 600,
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "position",
      "on": [
        {
          "events": {
            "type": "mousemove"
          },
          "update": "xy()"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "positionDot",
      "on": [
        {
          "events": {
            "type": "mousemove"
          },
          "update": "xy()"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "fill": {
            "value": "#000"
          },
          "text": {
            "value": "Text Label"
          }
        },
        "update": {
          "opacity": {
            "value": 1
          },
          "x": {
            "signal": "position[0]+20"
          },
          "y": {
            "signal": "position[1]+20"
          },
          "fontSize": {
            "value": 50
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "dot",
      "type": "symbol",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "fill": {
            "value": "#939597"
          },
          "stroke": {
            "value": "#652c90"
          },
          "x": {
            "value": 0
          },
          "y": {
            "value": 0
          }
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {
            "signal": "positionDot[0]"
          },
          "y": {
            "signal": "position[1]"
          },
          "size": {
            "value": 550
          },
          "opacity": {
            "value": 1
          }
        },
        "hover": {
          "opacity": {
            "value": 0.5
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/1dcd1034a1d8139b3de49f041ed1ed4b/spec.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works as expected if an initial value (using "init" or "value") is included in signal *position*:

```
"signals": [
{
  "name": "position",
  "init": [0, 0],
  "on": [
    {
      "events": {
        "type": "mousemove"
      },
      "update": "xy()"
    }
  ]
},
```

[View in Vega online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAB3GgBN6aAGwAGNTPg0yWVRpkQd4pABsIaANqgTCOGhA42RzO0kya4ulc1qAujISVqBwpOKYFqigmACeOPboCGwMEIhspCAAvjIMOApImAkgAB4xABQAlFl+2TZIdg5OLm4AImyY0iBBqNYgoXDhkdFxRUkpaRnZILn5hQ6lldWZASDIAE4A1pG9sfEOhcUdMgNQbAoJIeFwa2igAGY0pqa3IMRmDEUAxBpqWTIHHSir3eRQAKnBDgACAAySCYcGemSmMwKFy6OCQUDoMReb1MHzQAEYpsUXkYyCZnugmnQ3JZ-ABqABMvymOKB5MpjWctIklkJfmZrJkdwkmAAyjQAF5ovEE1ACNRIpFSOoNdAKdqdXZFCAxBBMNjPY7iU7nF4DQo3IEPJ64kEOT4ATgAzE6BE6AOx-EAQTBrNgbWUO9CfFQCJlQJ3Ckr2-EJJUydmgOUJlXTPKol6kjnGMzc5oSNqYel+H3J315qmOHmuPkCn1GGVx+UCRVTNgYrGxFsJYlTGDpa4vTuY7G9tBqSgCZXLTJAA)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution ! @Roy Ing. For curiosity, how does adding " init" or "value" implies a fix to the issue ?

Comment: Could be an issue or bug with Vega. Workaround by trial and error.